# Am I eligible for a refund of Social Security and Medicare taxes for when I was on an F-1 visa?

Tags: united-states, taxes, withholding, payroll-taxes, f1-student-visa

This question is for a friend. They came to the United States as a student in 2009 on OPT/F-1 visa. In November of 2011 they started to work for the Department of Defense as a teacher. They had Social Security and Medicare taxes withheld and not refunded. In August of 2012 they were converted to an H-1B visa.

Should they have been refunded the Social Security and Medicare taxes that were withheld for 2011, and possibly 2012? It seems to depend on whether they were considered a resident or nonresident alien for those tax years, according to [this](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Foreign-Student-Liability-for-Social-Security-and-Medicare-Taxes). The [Substantial Presence Test](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Substantial-Presence-Test) says as an F-1 student they are exempt. Would this count for 2011 and 2012, or just 2011? If they are due a refund, how should they go about getting it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A student on F1 working under the conditions of the OPT program is exempt from FICA taxes. Once you switch to H1b - you no longer have the exemption.

You can use [form 8316](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8316.pdf) and [form 843](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f843.pdf) to request the refund, if the employer cannot or will not refund the withholding. Employer is the first stop, but keep in mind that you have 3 years at most to request the refund after filing the tax returns for the year in question (or when they should have been filed, if you didn't).

[Detailed instructions here](https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/2339478-social-security-medicare-refund-for-f1-visa-working-on-optx).

Comment: So just to clarify, they should be refunded for all FICA taxes withheld until August 2012 when they switched to H-1B?

Comment: This is only true for F1 *non-residents*. (Although if the OP's friend hadn't been an international student in the U.S. prior to this, he is likely a non-resident as the first 5 calendar years as a student is exempt from the Substantial Presence Test.)